# Copy multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, multidimensional-array, concatenation

I try to use `concat` for a multidimensional array but it`s simply not working. What is the solution?

```
var f:Array = new Array(3, 4, 5, 6);
var t:Array = new Array("s","g");
var u:Array = new Array();
u.push(f);
u.push(t);
trace (u);      // output-->    3,4,5,6,s,g
trace (u[1]);   // output-->    s,g
var r:Array = new Array();
r.concat(u);
trace (" r : " + r);    // output-->    r :
trace (" r0: " + r[0]); // output-->    r0: undefined
```

Comment: concat **returns** the concatenated result, it does not affect the `r` array in your example. Try `r = r.concat(u);`.

Comment: oh, you beat me with 3 mins.. :)

Comment: @csomakk ..though, mine is a comment whereas yours is an answer ;)

Comment: yes, i made a project and debugged it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the answer is

```
 r = r.concat(u);
```

because the return of the concat is the result, and the inputs remain the same.